# Can I make money for a proposal in Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

If I create a good proposal on the Stack Exchange site, what benefits can I get?

Will I get money if my proposal is a great success?

I know that the only benefit in this is a mental pleasure of creating something useful, 
but I expect some economical benefits from it, so that I can promote and advertise my proposal on Stack Exchange.

Comment: And you expect the money to come from...?

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63347/19746

Comment: @Piskvor, where did you copy referral links [like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63347/19746) (or: why change the usual links into not having their title)? Using the plain old  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63347/i-have-531-points-on-so-can-i-get-a-free-iphone makes it much easier for us to decide whether to check the link or not.

Comment: @Arjan: Open *a* question, any question. Note the "link" link under question. Right-click, select Copy link address. Personally, I liked the old way better (with the title), but alas, it's apparently not to be.

Comment: @Arjan: Ah, I see that the title still has the old-style link with the text. Veeery good, thanks for nudging me to it.

Comment: Aha, @Piskvor, that's only used in questions, not in answers, I didn't see that! (So, as of now I'm copying links to answers and remove the hash, or copy an expanded link from the address bar.)

Comment: @Arjan: The referral links were introduced for tracking badge requirements http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/ , I assumed all links to questions were changed to this form. Turns out that you can right-click question title and copy its link.

Comment: why downvotes?(15 chars.)

Comment: @piemesons: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work#47635, specifically this part: *On Meta, an upvote indicates "I like this suggestion" or "I agree" and a downvote indicates "I don't like this suggestion" or "I disagree." Note that downvotes do not necessarily mean that you have asked a question or given an answer that is poorly-formed. This isn't an official rule, but it has become the de facto accepted community standard*

Comment: Will i get some points at-least for the successful proposal...?
Or you can encourage new proposal by giving them some points and they can use that point to give an advertisements here(you can also be more specific like , in the page where he has up-votes like that ) .
I think this idea will definitely help SX to rule thrown, because this is the best site to get the get dynamic answers . we can also say this as future's "Dynamic Search Engine"

Answer (score 7):

**None**

The only benefit is the feel good feeling that you started something but other then that, nothing. Nada. Zilch.

<sub>There may or may not be some badges involved.</sub>

Comment: but .. i expect  so some economical benefits from it.. so tat i can promote and advertise my proposal of stackExchange

Comment: @user151725: And I expected a magical unicorn! Even a non-magical unicorn would have been fine - heck, I'd have been quite happy just with a pony! And what did they give me?!? *A feel-good feeling*!

Answer (score 4):

You should probably read [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) on the StackOverflow blog. Specifically this part:

> ### We Will Match Effort With Funds
>
> Any community that shows sufficient effort and innovative ideas to promote their site will be offered a budget and resources to make those ideas happen. Think of it as matching funds — except we’re matching effort, innovation, resources, and ideas from the community. And it has to come from within your community. You’re the experts, not us!

So if you have a great idea for a site, [propose it, get followers, get sample questions, and get it built](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)... You don't have to spend your own money. If a community shows an effort to promote their site, Stack Overflow will spend more money to help with promotions to make your efforts more effective.

Comment: **This sounds so out of context** that it is simply *wrong.* Nobody says *"drive people to it any way you can"* and we'll take care of you. People who put effort into these sites do so out of an *implicit* desire to see them succeed. That's their reward. If a community shows an effort to promote their site, we will spend more money to help with promotions to make their efforts more effective. I'm *hoping* that's what you meant, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Robert: "If a community shows an effort to promote their site, we will spend more money to help with promotions to make their efforts more effective" -- Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say. My apologies if I didn't clarify that. Please feel free to edit my answer and improve it!

Comment: @Robert: Specifically I was responding to: "but I expect some economical benefits from it, so that I can promote and advertise my proposal on Stack Exchange", my point being, don't pay for advertising. Build a community and then let the Stack Exchange team do paid advertising

Comment: Unhandled Exception: that's what I thought you meant. Sometimes the written word doesn't sound the same in my head as someone else meant it. I just envisioned people coming after me for their cut of the payola because "I said... blah blah blah..." I added your/my quote to your original post. But, seriously, if I changed the *meaning*, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Robert: HAHA -- Yeah, when I reread it, I saw how it could be read that way. Sometimes when I write words I don't convey the meaning of my thoughts :-) Your edits make my answer much more clear without altering my meaning at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you will receive money.  However, if you propose a Stack Exchange site which you want and it is successful, you will get the successful Stack Exchange site you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a site to make you money, Stack Exchange probably isn't the best way. Stack Exchange is the one taking the most risk and bringing the most to the table in this case.